# angular search filter results

Tags: angularjs, search, filter

When the first letter is entered in the input, the results show all strings that contain the letter, instead of results starting with the letter. Is there another type of built in filter or attribute?

```
<input ng-model="search.RegionName">
<div class="item" ng-repeat="region in DividedRegionList | filter:search:strict" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gcVYfZXTqsDU1Z7REU2I?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('filterSample', []);
app.controller('filterCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    messages: ['first', 'second', '3rd', 'fourth', 'fifth']
  }

  $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
    var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
    return lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
  }
});
```

And template:

```
    <ul border="1px" ng-repeat="msg in data.messages | filter:search:startsWith">
      <li>{{msg}}</li>
    </ul>
```